# Программное добавление Relative Layout в активити

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть проблема с программным добавлением Relative Layout, точнее с задаванием rules для Relative.
Собственно, код

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rootParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    View view2 = new SimpleView(this);

    relativeLayout.addView(view2, viewLayout);

    setContentView(relativeLayout, rootParams);
}
```

Проблема в строчке

```
     viewLayout.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
```

центрирование не происходит, картинка в левом верхнем углу как была так и есть, что-то я где-то упустил, хотя делал по примеру.

UPD.

```
public class SimpleView extends View{

private static final String TAG = SimpleView.class.getSimpleName();
private Bitmap bitmap;

public SimpleView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public SimpleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

}

Comment: Я создал пример скопировав ваш код и все работает - View по центру. Значит вы или как-то не так тестируете ил проблема в SimpleView.

Comment: это-то меня и удивляет, добавил SimpleView класс

Comment: а тестирую на Samsung Note 3, тут как бы ничего особенного

Comment: Есть подозрение что ваш SimpleView по каким то причинам не WRAP_CONTENT а MATCH_PARENT. Можете проверить это, например закрасив его в красный цвет?

Comment: И еще попробуйте вместо SimpleView использовать обычный Button и посмотреть будет ли он по центру.

Comment: В случае когда поменял свою кастомную view на стандартный Button, то выравнивание по центру произошло... Странно. значит какой то параметр у вью надо явно задать?

Comment: Проверьте таки что SimpleView не MATCH_PARENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть подозрение что вам нужно переопределить `onMeasure()`:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Только нужно убедиться что bitmap != null.

UPD. гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12266899/onmeasure-custom-view-explanation) если английский позволяет.

Comment: да, действительно, при создании кастомной вьюхи размеры ее были под размер экрана